# Latino Elongated, XeTeX and small capitals

Tags: xetex, fontspec, small-caps

I'm using the Latino Elongated LET font with XeTeX and I can't get small capitals to display:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\lelong{Latino Elongated LET}
\newfontfamily\lelongsc[SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Latino Elongated LET}

\begin{document}

\lelong \scshape Small capitals

\lelongsc \scshape Small capitals

\newfontinstance\scshape[Letters=SmallCaps]{Latino Elongated LET}

\lelong \scshape Small capitals

\end{document}
```

gives me three lines with normal characters:

[image: small caps failure]

How can I get small capitals? It is possible that this font is lacking sc functionalities?

**Note:**

The third attempt (`\newfontinstance`) gives a warning in the logs:

> Package fontspec Warning: 
>       OpenType feature 'Letters=SmallCaps' (+smcp) not
>   available
>       for font "Latino Elongated LET Plain:1.0/ICU" at 10.95pt, 
>       with script 'Latin',
>       and language 'Default'.

Comment: I get the message that small caps are not present in the font. You can't have what is not in the font.

Comment: have you checked if the font really has the small caps feature with a `otfinfo -f /path/to/font`?

Comment: @egreg: OK, so maybe I need another Latino Elongated font?

Comment: @henrique: the file is a ttf, so I can't run that. Is there an equivalent for true type/T1 fonts?

Comment: @Raphink a few truetype fonts do have opentype features that can be displayed with `otfinfo`... If it doesn't, the font simply lacks the functionality and you can't have smallcaps with it. (Some commercial fonts come in bundles with a separated file for smallcaps... if that is the case, you'll need to create a `\newfontface` to use it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font is a TrueType font that doesn't have "small caps" functionality. That is, the font just doesn't *have* any small caps.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't contain small caps in a private Unicode area?

Comment: @Andrey: that was actually my question, I'd love to know how to know that.

Comment: @Raphink Open the font with **fontforge** or another utility (I have **OTM_Light**) and look at the glyphs. I can confirm that there is nothing in the PUA.

Comment: OK, thanks. I don't have fontforge. I thought fontconfig had a tool for that, maybe `fc-cat` can tell me this?

Comment: @Raphink `fc-cat` only lists fonts known to the font library of fontconfig. Look at http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

You can cheat:

```
\newcommand\fakesc[1]{\scalebox{0.7}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
```

Some things to note:

- This requires the graphicx package
- Uppercase letters in the `fakesc` scope get lost. (Although I'm sure some TeX-fu can fix that...
- The actual amount of scaling should probably depend on the exact font used...

Comment: I've actually cheated already in another way. Eventually, I'll see about purchasing the OTF version of the font which I believe has proper sc.

Answer (score 1):

I found a cleaner solution:

- open the TTF in fontforge;
- create small caps;
- save the font as OTF;
- use the new font;
- remember to not distribute non-free modified fonts on github ;-)

Comment: So long as the font licence allows you to do this.

Comment: The font doesn't allow me to redistribute, but can it prevent me from making private changes? Isn't that the same as stretching it in inkscape for example?